# Adding Plug-in dependencies in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I try to import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile for a Plug-in project in Eclipse  I get the following error:

```
The type org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

How do I add it to Plug-in Dependencies?

Comment: Getting the same error for "org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput," but I cannot find it when searching through the plug-in selection. Am I missing a .jar file containing that dependencies?

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Needed to add "org.eclipse.ui" to Imported Packages in the MANIFEST file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `org.eclipse.core.resources` to the 'Required Plug-ins' on the 'Dependencies' tab of the MANIFEST.MF editor for your plugin.

Comment: Woo, that did it. Thank you!